# How to fix error C2511: overloaded member function not found in C++?

Tags: c++, class, parameters

I have a problem to pass my own class as a parameter.

Here is my codes:

PayloadContainer.h

```
namespace Project
{
    namespace C
    {
        namespace Helper
        {
            class PayloadItem
            {
            public:
                string Key;
                string Value;
                char Type;
                char Mode;
                char IsArray;
                int FieldCount;
                char FieldType;
                int RowCount;
            };

            class PayloadContainer
            {
            public:
                PayloadContainer( const char *Command );
                PayloadContainer(void);
                ~PayloadContainer(void);

            public:
                vector<PayloadItem> PayloadItems;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

ParseBinary.h

```
namespace Project
{
    namespace C
    {
        namespace Helper
        {
            class ParseBinary
            {
            public:
                ParseBinary(void);
                ~ParseBinary(void);

            private:
                void WriteRequestToBinary( const char *BinFileName );
                void WriteRequestRecord( unsigned char file[], PayloadItem& item, string charSet );
            };
        }
    }
}
```

ParseBinary.cpp

```
namespace Project
{
    namespace C
    {
        namespace Helper
        {
            void ParseBinary::WriteRequestToBinary( const char *BinFileName )
            {
                unsigned char in;

                // Do Something

                for (auto &item : _payload->PayloadItems)
                {
                    // Do Something

                    WriteRequestRecord( in, (Helper::PayloadItem)item, _payload->CharSet );
                }
            }

            void ParseBinary::WriteRequestRecord( unsigned char file[], PayloadItem& item, string charSet )
            {
                -----> here, I get "error C2511: overloaded member function not found".
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is iterating vector where PayloadItem is my own class, and pass that class to a function.

But, when I build it I get this error C2511: overloaded member function not found error.

Please tell me where to fix this.

**EDIT**

This is the error message.

Error   9   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PayloadItem'    c:\webdev\Project.c.helper\ParseBinary.h    46  1   Project.C.Helper
error C2511: overloaded member function not found in 'Project::C::Helper::ParseBinary'  c:\webdev\Project.c.helper\ParseBinary.cpp  958 1   Project.C.Helper

Comment: Please show the actual line of code that causes the error message.

Comment: @BrianBi I have edited including the full error message.